# Parsing Multipart/Mixed with Multipart/Alternative body in java

Tags: java, email, multipart, jakarta-mail

I'm getting emails from a client where they have nested a multipart/alternative message inside a multipart/mixed message. When I get the body of the message it just returns the multipart/alternative level when what I really want is the text/html part which is contained in the multipart/alternative.

I've looked through the javadocs for javax.mail and I can't find a simple way to get the body of a bodypart that is itself a multipart or skip the first multipart/mixed part and go into the multipart/alternative body to read the text/html and text/plain pieces.

The email structure looks like this:

```
...
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
    boundary="----=_Part_19487_1145362154.1418138792683"

------=_Part_19487_1145362154.1418138792683
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
    boundary="----=_Part_19486_1391901275.1418138792683"

------=_Part_19486_1391901275.1418138792683
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

...

------=_Part_19486_1391901275.1418138792683
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

...

------=_Part_19486_1391901275.1418138792683--

------=_Part_19487_1145362154.1418138792683--
```

This is an outline of the code used to parse the emails:

```
Message [] found = fldr.search(searchCondition);           
for (int i = 0; i < found.length; i++) {
    Message m = found[i];
    Object o = m.getContent();
    if (o instanceof Multipart) {
        log.info("**This is a Multipart Message.  ");
        Multipart mp = (Multipart)o;
        log.info("The Multipart message has " + mp.getCount() + " parts.");
        for (int j = 0; j < mp.getCount(); j++) {
            BodyPart b = mp.getBodyPart(j);

            // Loop if the content type is multipart then get the content that is in that part,
            // make it the new container and restart the loop in that part of the message.
            if (b.getContentType().contains("multipart")) {
                mp = (Multipart)b.getContent();
                j = 0;
                continue;
            }

            log.info("This content type is " + b.getContentType());

            if(!b.getContentType().contains("text/html")) {
                continue;
            }

            Object o2 = b.getContent();
            if (o2 instanceof String) {
                <do things with content here>
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It appears to keep stopping at the second boundary and not parsing anything further. In the case of the above message it stops at   boundary="----=_Part_19486_1391901275.1418138792683" and never gets to the text of the message.

Comment: What does `log.info("This content type is " + b.getContentType());` give ?

Comment: "This content type is multipart/alternative;" When it works it says " This content type is text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"

Comment: Every time, for each loop turn ?

Comment: It says:
**This is a Multipart Message. / 
The Multipart message has 1 parts. /  
This content type is multipart/alternative; /  
 boundary="----=_Part_19486_1391901275.1418138792683" / 
exits the loop and tries parsing the next message in the found array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this block :

```
if (b.getContentType().contains("multipart"))
{
    mp = (Multipart)b.getContent();
    j = 0;
    continue;
}
```

You set `j` to 0 and ask the loop to continue, hoping it will start again at zero. But the increment operation `j++` will come before and your loop will start at 1, not 0.

Set `j` to -1 to solve your issue.

```
if (b.getContentType().contains("multipart"))
{
    mp = (Multipart)b.getContent();
    j = -1;
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I've been on vacation for the past few days. So far it works in the test environment but not in production.

Comment: Weird. Before it was failing in both environment ?

Comment: Undetermined, the test emails were slightly different before and were always passing. Finally got to test with identical emails and it's still not working in prod. Trying to figure out why.

Comment: If it's working in test but not in production, some differences (code, test data, conf) must remain

Comment: Yes, trying to figure out exactly what the difference is.

Comment: Old, non-working, code was moved to prod. Got the correct code in and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code and failed for me as well.

In my case, `b.getContentType()` returns all uppercase characters (e.g. "TEXT/HTML; charset=UTF-8"). So I have converted that to lowercase and it worked.

```
String contentType=b.getContentType().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);

if(!contentType.contains("text/html")) {
   continue;
}
```

Comment: Why is it that when I print the content type to the log it's always in lower case?

Comment: If that's lowercase, no problem. I think it's related to which e-mail client library you use. Some e-mail clients return uppercase (I have tested on sun's IMAP implementation with gmail).