# Compare Btween multipart/mixed and multipart/alternative

Tags: java, email

I'm getting emails from a client multipart/mixed message (with download URL), When I get the email body of the message by using code in Java it just returns the text email without
an HTML part of the message(download URL).
but when I tried to send the same email I got it as a multipart/alternative (we get the HTML part of the message(download URL)).
this is the content we use to get the mail body: Content-Type","text/html; charset=charset="UTF-8".

Comment: anyone can help me in this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27387202/parsing-multipart-mixed-with-multipart-alternative-body-in-java?rq=2